# Flutter Web SDK for a videochat

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, agora.io, videochat

For app projects that require a video chat system, I mostly used Agora or Zegocloud. Does anyone know of an SDK for the Flutter Web?

agora_rtc_engine only supports the flutter web up to version 6.0.0, does anyone know of an alternative?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.